# Setting the unit vector ratio gives a '! Dimension too large' error

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, 3d, matlab2tikz

I have a Delaunay-triangulated surface generated in MATLAB, which I would prefer to render in tikz. I use Nico Schlömer's [`matlab2tikz`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGOoF.png) script to generate the standalone tex file.

The MATLAB result looks like this:

[image: matlab out]

When I compile the standalone .tex file generated by matlab2tikz, however, it looks like this:

[image: matlab2tikz]

In the MATLAB image, the data aspect ratio is set with MATLAB's `daspect` command, like so:

```
daspect([1000 1000 1])
```

I have tried to accomplish the same thing using `unit vector ratio` in pgfplots. However, it makes no difference how I set it. In every case, I get this error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
\relax 
l.7398 \end{axis}
```

Any one of these pgfplots settings will cause the error:

```
unit vector ratio 1 1 1
unit vector ratio 1 1
unit vector ratio 1000 1000 1
unit vector ratio 1 1 0.001
```

or any of the above with *

and also, for the sake of experiment (I don't want a 1 1 1 ratio, it will just give me a flat surface):

```
axis equal
axis equal image
```

The `plot box ratio` approach [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127048/set-the-axis-range-according-to-the-data-range-that-is-no-scales-for-axis) doesn't work either - same error.

I figure it must be possible to make this work. The tikz rendering looks very nice otherwise. The data set has about 7000 lines, so I can't post it here, and anyway it works without the unit vector transformation, so I don't think that the data is the problem.

Here is the code for the axis (with the large colormap omitted!):

```
\begin{axis}[%
%width=6.82222222222222in,
%height=3.40720720720721in,
area legend,
unit vector ratio = 1 1,
view={-37.5}{30},
scale only axis,
xmin=545550,
xmax=584400,
xlabel={Ost [m]},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=5542050,
ymax=5569500,
ylabel={Nord [m]},
ymajorgrids,
zmin=8.46471544296322,
zmax=16.9194594285807,
zlabel={$\text{U [ms}^{\text{-1}}\text{]}$},
zmajorgrids,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left
```

The complete source may be [obtained here.](http://pastebin.ca/2454210)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel actually, compat=newest... is that the problem?

Comment: what happens when you use `unit vector ratio 2 2 1`

Comment: You can use `z post scale=0.1` to reduce the z axis length to one tenth of its default length. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't allow you to specify the ratio of the axis lengths explicitly, though. In any case, you should note that you want the unit vector lengths for x and y to be much shorter than for z (so you should be trying things like `unit vector ratio=1 1 1000` instead of `unit vector ratio=1000 1000 1`)

Comment: @percusse `unit vector ratio 2 2 1` gives the same error.

Comment: @Jake I guess I forgot to mention that I had also tried `<x y z> post scale`. None of my previous attempts worked. It works with `z post scale=0.1` (but not with `z post scale=0.01`!) but is not the result I am aiming for -- the resulting graph is very flat and I still have the problem that the x and y axes are differently scaled.

Comment: @StephenBosch: Just to clarify: You do want to get the graph to look flatter, right? So it looks more similar to the Matlab output? Could you maybe try to generate a dummy data set containing just a couple of points from your real dataset, so we can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Jake I want the output to look flatter, but only as a consequence of having x and y equally scaled. I can pastebin the file, it's only about 380k.

Comment: @StephenBosch: That might be a good idea

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10652/discussion-between-stephen-bosch-and-jake)

Comment: @Jake I have added a link to the complete source to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a more satisfying solution to the problem, and it makes use of `plot box ratio` after all. It turns out that you cannot use the values from `daspect` to set the plot ratio: they are too large.

So which values *do* you use?

The current axis object in MATLAB gives the answer. With the figure to be exported current (either by invoking `figure(<figurehandle>)` or clicking the figure), get the axis handle. The attribute `PlotBoxAspectRatio` is functionally equivalent to `plot box ratio`. You need this value before invoking `matlab2tikz`. Here is the MATLAB code:

```
a1 = gca;
plotBoxAspect = get(a1,'PlotBoxAspectRatio');
plotBoxStr = sprintf('plot box ratio = %d %d %d',plotBoxAspect(1),plotBoxAspect(2),plotBoxAspect(3));
matlab2tikz('outputfile.tex','standalone',true,'extraAxisOptions',plotBoxStr);
```

The result is about as close to the original MATLAB surface plot as you can reasonably expect:

[image: pgfplots corrected]

Using this method, there is no need to manually set the unit vectors.

Answer (score 6):

You could work around the problem by providing the `x`, `y` and `z` unit vectors explicitly yourself:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
area legend,
xlabel={Ost [m]},
xmajorgrids,
ylabel={Nord [m]},
x={(0.0001cm,0.00005cm)}, y={(-0.0001cm,0.00005cm)}, z={(0cm,0.2cm)},
ymajorgrids,
zmin=8.46471544296322,
zmax=16.9194594285807,
zlabel={$\text{U [ms}^{\text{-1}}\text{]}$},
zmajorgrids,
axis lines*=left,
colormap/violet
]

\addplot3[patch,forget plot]  table[point meta=\thisrow{c}]{data.dat};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. As long as the absolute values of the components of the unit vectors for x and y are the same, I should get equal scaling. I see you didn't bother with my huge colormap ;)