# Error message: Dimension too large

Tags: pgfplots

I am graphing the restriction of a cubic function on the domain [0, 20]. The function has a maximum value of about 3,079 at about 11.5.  To get some view of it, I use the specification `unit vector ratio={1 100}`.  `PgfPlots` gives me the error message "Dimension too large."  How do I get this to plot?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,unit vector ratio={1 100},clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=20,
    domain=-2:0.5,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-100,ymax=3000,
    restrict y to domain=-100:3000,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={},ytick={},
    extra x ticks={11.547},
    extra x tick labels={$20/\sqrt{3}$},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-2:20,blue] {400*x - x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reduce to a real MWE. Does this help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133923

Comment: @LaRiFaRi  I do not know why the code is not compiling.  The preferred answer to the question that you suggested does not apply to my code.

Comment: Why don't you just remove both `axis equal image,unit vector ratio={1 100},`?

Comment: @percusse  I did remove `axis equal image,unit vector ratio={1 100},` as you suggested.  The graph is fine, but it is too high.  The graph occupies 2/3 of a page.  With a command like `unit vector ratio={1 250}` or `unit vector ratio={1 500}`, I can get a nice graph that does not occupy so much of the page. Do you know why it is not compiling?

Comment: Just use width and height keys to resize the axes

Answer (score 2):

Using all three of these:

- `width=6in`
- `axis equal image`
- `unit vector ratio={1 100}`

makes no sense. Most of what `axis equal image` does is to set `unit vector ratio={1 1}` which you immediately override with the other setting. The only other thing it does is to shrink the axis box to fit the axis min and max values at the specified `unit vector ratio`, which renders the `width` key setting totally impossible to reach because of the selected unit vector ratio.

Just let `pgfplots` do its job (use the `width` and `height` keys) and everything works fine. Here's a truly minimal example of that at work<sup>1</sup>:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples=100,
    width=6in,
    height=4in, % or whatever height you want
%    axis equal image,
%    unit vector ratio={1 250},
  ]
    \addplot[domain=-2:20] {400*x - x^3};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sup>1</sup>: I've said this before, and I'll say it again: putting all of the excess styling code in all of your questions just makes them harder to read and understand what you're after. Please, make some effort to determine what is actually needed to show the problem you want to solve, before just posting all of it.

As I've also mentioned before, you are fighting `pgfplots` tooth and nail to get the axes to look the way you want, while at the same time, the functions/other things you are plotting don't really need the advanced capabilities of `pgfplots`. If you really want this level of control over things `pgfplots` tries so hard to hide from you (axis scaling, in this instance), you may find it easier to work in `tikz` directly, without involving `pgfplots`. Here's some code that gives the output you're after without having to fight `pgfplots`' default styling/scaling:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  axisline/.style={latex-latex},
  tickmark/.style={gray},
  ticklabel/.style={font=\tiny,fill=white,text=black},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25in,y=0.001in]
  \foreach \y in {500,1000,...,3000} {% y-ticks
    \draw[tickmark] (2pt,\y) -- ++(-4pt,0) % draw the tick mark
      node[left,ticklabel] {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\y}$}; % label it
  }
  \foreach \x in {-2,2,4,...,20} {% x-ticks
    \draw[tickmark] (\x,2pt) -- ++(0,-4pt) % draw the tick mark
      node[below,ticklabel] {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}$}; % label it
  }
  \draw[tickmark] (11.547,2pt) -- ++(0,-4pt) % an extra x tick
    node[below,ticklabel] {$20/\sqrt{3}$}; % its label
  \draw[axisline] (0,3000) +(0,0.5cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-100) -- +(0,-0.5cm); % the y-axis
  \draw[axisline] (-2,0) +(-0.5cm,0) -- (20,0) -- +(0.5cm,0) node[below right] {$x$}; % the x-axis
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-2.1,-100) rectangle (20.1,3000); % "restrict y to domain"
    \draw[blue,domain=-2:20,samples=100] plot (\x,400*\x - \x^3);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This command does give me the axes printed by `pgfplots`.
\tikzset{
  axisline/.style={latex-latex},
  tickmark/.style={gray},
  ticklabel/.style={font=\tiny,fill=white,text=black},
}
I am not insisting to use `pgfplots` to graph functions.  This is the first time that I have seen a nice plot of a function with `TikZ`.  I am now inclined to just use `TikZ'.

Comment: I will need some explanations to your code.  I looked on page 34 of the manual at the following web site. 

http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf

Comment: What is `\draw (2pt,\y) -- ++(-4pt,0)` instructing `TikZ` to plot?  I think "(2pt,\y)" is the rectangular coordinates for a point 2pt to the right of the y-axis and \y above the x-axis.  What are the units for \y? There are no units in the command `\foreach \y in {500,1000,...,3000}`.  I think `(-4pt,0)` is the rectangular coordinates for a point 4pt to the left of the y-axis and \y above the x-axis.  I guess `-- ++` instructs `TikZ` to draw a tick mark between these points.  The graph shows the tick marks are symmetric across the y-axis, though.

Comment: One more question about you code ... for now.  Why do you have `\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}` between "$"?  I looked in section 74 (beginning on page 714 of the `TikZ` manual) and it didn't have this command between "$".

Comment: Thanks for giving me an alternative to using `pgfplots`.

Comment: (I'm responding with multiple comments because you have asked so many questions... please, use chat for this, not comments...) First off, you are looking at an outdated version of the manual. You should look at the manual for the version you actually have installed, which I highly doubt is `v2.10-CVS`. Use `texdoc pgf` on a command line/terminal to open the documentation corresponding to the version you have installed.

Comment: `(2pt,\y)` is just an x-y coordinate pair, located as you correctly thought. If the ordinate/abscissa is given as a TeX dimension (as in `2pt`), this is an absolute measurement, independent of the scaling of the TikZ picture (that is, `x=<dim>,y=<dim>`. I did it this so that the axis ticks will look the same regardless of the scaling of the axes you have chosen.

Comment: The tick marks are centered because they start `2pt` to the right of the y-axis and then I use the relative coordinate specifier `++` to move _relative to_ the current point in the path. So we end up with a line from `2pt` to the right of the axis to `2pt` left of the axis (or `4pt` to the left of the starting point).

Comment: `\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}` is used instead of just `\x` so that the number has `,` as a thousands separator, which would not happen otherwise. There are many options to configure how this command will print numbers, so I used it so that the style is separate from the content and is easy to change if desired.

Comment: I have to leave soon.  So, I will ask for clarification on your reply here. You have the optional command `[x=0.25in,y=0.001in]`. I guess this is a command for scaling. Is it a 250:1 scaling ratio? Does this instruct `TikZ` to measure a quarter of an inch between units on the x-axis and a thousandth of an inch between units on the y-axis?

Comment: I now understand that "++" is a command for relative positioning.  What about "--" preceding it in your code?  Why do you have `\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}` between "$".  You said that you have `\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}` instead of `\pgfmathprintnumber\x` to separate place values in an integer. Why do you have `$\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}$`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21271/discussion-between-paul-gessler-and-adelyn).